# Can't change .PHONY target's prerequisite name in GNU Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu

Can someone please explain why 
running `make clean`
prints

> Target clean

with below makefile

```
.PHONY: all
all: clean

clean:
    echo "Target clean"
```

But running

> make clean_local

throws exception

> No rule to make target 'clean_local'

when I change makefile to

```
.PHONY: all
all: clean_local

clean_local:
    echo "Target clean_local"
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce you second exercise (it prints "Target clean_local" for me, twice, by the way). Are you sure you didn't have typo?

Comment: Ah, looks like I found the cause of the issue. Makefile I passed in the question was called from another makefile that didn't have  clean_local target but had clean target (and was calling clean target of the one I paste here). That's why it worked for clean but didn't work for clean_local. Thanks for looking at it!